# Discrete mathematics- beginner set problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A = {1, 2, 4, 5}
B = {0, 2, 8}
Considering the sets above are the following correct?

(A U B )\(A ∩ B) = {0, 1, 4, 5, 8}

(A\B) U (B\A) = {0, 1, 4, 5, 8}

(\A ∩ B ) U ( A ∩ \B) = {0, 1, 4, 5, 8}

Answer (score 1):

Just freaking do them!

$A\cup B = \{0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8\} $ because that's what you get when you combine the elements together.

$A\cap B = \{2\}$ because those are all the elements the two sets have in common.

So $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$ are all the elements of $\{0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8\}$ that are not in $\{2\}$.  And that is $\{0, 1,  4, 5, 8\}$ because this isn't brain science and any squid can follow directions.

...

Actually, the concept of $\setminus A$ may be unique.  Is that supposed to mean the compliment of $A$?  What is the implied universal set?

Comment: The RS are the answers I came up with while the LS is the question. I’m just asking for a double check.

Comment: Also yes it is compliment

Comment: What is the universal set?  All integers?  All real numbers?  Every concept in the universe?  Just the numbers we see listed.  I guess it doesn't matter in these three expressions will always be the same set: All the elements that are in one or the other set but not both.

Comment: It was just the numbers in the sets listed. You answered the question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just work them out. Look up the meaning of "union" and "intersection" and understand what they mean. Then use this newfound understanding to compute the expressions on the left, and check they're the same as the ones on the right. Honestly, it's not rocket science.

If you want, you could even write a small Python script to compute the answers for you. [Here's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) the commands you'll need. For example, the first expression would be (A | B) - (A & B) in Python syntax.

Comment: They have been worked out to get those answers the work was not included.

Comment: Then what is your question exactly?  Did you do them correctly?  Well, yes....